# Get one String from a Method into another Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openfiledialog

I'm currently writing a program and I'm very new to this topic.
I've started with a program where you can select a zip file and unzip it.

For both things (selecting, unzip) I've used one button. So there is a button for selecting and one button for unzipping.

Now after selecting the file I wanna put the directory into a string, so the unzip method can unzip it.

But I don't know how to put this directory into a string.
I've tried
`string fileDir = fdlg.FileName` but this string doesn't work in the unzip method.

How can I fix this?

Select Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Test - Selec ZIP File";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:";
    fdlg.Filter = "Only ZIP Files|*.zip";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `fdlg` is only scoped to the button click event handler, so you can't access it from other event handlers.  You store the filename in `textBox1.Text` so you should probably be pulling it from that in other event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possibility could be to declare a `string` variable on class level and NOT inside the event:

```
string fileDir = "";

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Test - Selec ZIP File";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:";
    fdlg.Filter = "Only ZIP Files|*.zip";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;

        //copy here the filename
        fileDir = fdlg.FileName;
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use `fileDir` throughout the entire class.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

When you show the path in the textbox, at the same time you can store the path in the string

```
textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName;
string path=textBox1.Text;
```